# Loopback 3 updateAll filter is not working

Tags: loopback, update-all, loopback3

I have the following model in Loopback 3:

```json
    {
      "name": "rehearsalTest",
      "base": "PersistedModel",
      "idInjection": true,
      "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "creationDate": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "userId": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "courseId": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "templateId": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "testId": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "grade": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": false
        }
      },
      "validations": [],
      "relations": {},
      "acls": [
        {
          "accessType": "*",
          "principalType": "ROLE",
          "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
          "permission": "DENY"
        },
        {
          "accessType": "*",
          "principalType": "ROLE",
          "principalId": "$authenticated",
          "permission": "ALLOW"
        }
      ],
      "methods": {}
    }
```

It seems pretty trivial, and my data in Mongo is shown like this:

[image]

I just want to update the grade in an already created row, filtering by `testId`. I've done this multiple times, but this one doesn't work, for reasons I cannot seem to fathom.

First I tried with:

```js
await RehearsalTest.updateAll({testId: testId}, {grade: grade}, (err, data) => { 
  console.log('rehearsalTest.updateAll', err, data);
});
```

This returns a `{count: 0}`.

So I tried with like, because sometimes it works:

```js
await RehearsalTest.updateAll({testId: {like: testId}}, {grade: grade}, (err, data) => { 
  console.log('rehearsalTest.updateAll', err, data);
});
```

Which throws this exception:

```
Error: The testId property has invalid clause {"like":"60afbc93f30a9f7807fc95d1"}: Expected a string or RegExp
```

The funny thing being that if I go to the loopback explorer and filter, it works flawlessly:

[image]

I tried also with the `find` and `findOne`, without luck. Either it doesn't return anything without the `like` clause, or it returns the exception shown above.

Any ideas? I'll be forever thankful.

**EDIT**
It seems that the string that is in the database is not exactly the same as the one I'm comparing it to. But I haven't found out exactly what is happening. This console.log:

```
console.log(`"${rehearsalTest.testId}"`, `"${testId}"`,
          `${rehearsalTest.testId}`, `${testId}`,        
          `"${rehearsalTest.testId}"` === `"${testId}"`,
          `${rehearsalTest.testId}` === `${testId}`,
          rehearsalTest.testId === testId,
          rehearsalTest.testId == testId,
          );
```

returns:

```
"60b652d4e31a1d54e086570d" "60b652d4e31a1d54e086570d" 60b652d4e31a1d54e086570d 60b652d4e31a1d54e086570d 
true true false true
```

So obviously something is making these two strings not completely equal, but right now I can't really see **what**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem was that my function was receiving `testId` directly from the object `test`, as `test.id`.

This `id`, even if it's displayed as a `string` in the `console.log`, internally it's an object, so nothing was comparing correctly because of this.

When I changed test.id with `"${test.id}"` everything worked.

I'll proceed to kill myself now, thank you.